# Convolution kernel for semi-circular law

Tags: convolution

For the first incomplete moment of the semi-circular law
$$f(t)=t\times\sqrt{\max(1-t^2,0)}~,$$
is there a kernel function $k(\cdot)$ that integrates it to zero?
$$\int k(x-t)\; f(t) dt=0\quad \forall x\in[-1,1]~.$$
It would have to be a proper kernel in the sense that $k(u)\geq0$ and $\int k(u)du=1$.

Comment: Of course not: there is no opportunity for cancellation.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "cancellation"?

Comment: One way an integral can vanish is if the positive values of the integrand cancel the negative values, as with $\int_0^{2\pi} \sin x dx=0$.  But if the integrand is non-negative this phenomenon cannot occur.  How else can the integral be $0$?  If the integrand vanishes over the range of integration.

Comment: You are right, I mis-spoke initially and have now corrected the question so that the integrand has both positive and negative values. This updated version is the question I indeed intended to pose initially, and I thank you for having pointed out the initial mis-statement.

Comment: What's the fourier transform of your $f$?

Comment: I am not completely sure. There is a formula for the Fourier transform of the semi-circular law here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeriesSemicircle.html but it involves a Bessel function of the first kind, and I do not know if it can be modified to pertain to the first incomplete moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your convolution is over the reals.

The Fourier transform $\hat f(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\exp(-itx)dx=\int_{-1}^1  {\sqrt{1-x^2}} \exp(-itx)\,dx$ is real-analytic and hence has isolated roots, and hence is non-vanishing on a dense set of reals. Since $k$ is integrable, its  Fourier transform  $\hat k$ is continuous.  For the convolution $f*k$ to vanish you would need the pointwise product $\hat f(t) \hat k(t)$ to vanish for all $t$.  This implies $\hat k$ is identically $0$ which implies $k$ must be indentically $0$.  So there is no non-trivial integrable function $k$ for which $f*k$ vanishes everywhere.  The restriction that $k$ be non-negative is not needed.

The real-analyticity of $\hat f$ follows from the DCT or by direct calculations with formulas related to  [Hankel transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_transform#Relation_to_the_Fourier_transform_(circularly_symmetric_case)) applied to the indicator function of the unit disk in the plane.

Comment: I think you mean $\hat{f}(t)=\int_{-1}^{+1}x\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$. But nonetheless your demonstration is correct: there is no integrable kernel that would work. I just have a feeling that there is a non-integrable one, i.e., one that decays of order $1/|x|$ as $|x|\to\infty$. But that was not the question I asked, so I mark your answer as accepted .

Comment: You're right.  Corrected, and thanks for the catch!